# Geopoints of areas in world

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, location, openstreetmap

Is there maybe (although i doubt but you never know) some free (or not free) database of all areas in world (or just cities) described with geo polygons.

For example:
Soho, London : [(latitude1, longitude1), (latitude2, longitude2), (latitude3, longitude3) ... ]

I know that openstreetmap has some free stuff but I haven find anything like this.

Any information is helpful!

Thanks,
Ivan

Comment: So if you already found OpenStreetMap what's wrong with it? It has such areas, either a simple bbox when searching with Nominatim, or even the city boundary as a polygon (not available for every city).

Comment: Perhaps Ivan isn't very familiar with OpenStreetMap? Ivan, the boundaries are indeed available in OpenStreetMap - here's Stockholm for example: http://www.openstreetmap.org/browse/relation/398021 - so if you want good answers to your question, it would help if you could say what it is about that data that doesn't already fulfil your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [MapIt Global](http://global.mapit.mysociety.org/) service may help. For any co-ordinate, it returns the administrative boundaries that cover it. If you have a list of cities you're interested in, you can simply query their service and get the shapes of their boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) web site. They have free gazetteer data sets available for world countries, including coordinates for capital cities, towns, parks, airports, business centers, etc. I know you asked for polygons but in my extensive travels across the net I haven't found anything that meets that requirement - not for free anyway.